# contact form 7 checkbox to send two different emails

Tags: wordpress, contacts, contact-form-7

I created a form with 2 check boxes (**Infographics AND WEBEX Video**). So when the user clicked on **Infographics** checkbox for an example and click the submit button, they will receive an email with the URL link to download the pdf.

Likewise, for **WEBEX** checkbox, the user will receive a different email with the URL link to watch the video. When the user clicked both check boxes, they will receive an email with both links.

How do I do that?

Comment: Have you explored at your end first?

Answer (score 0):

i suggest Ninja Form + Ninja Form Conditional Logic, check https://mediaspotstudio.in and find estimate cost online Menu